# C++ - Issue of using function pointer to member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, typedef

I've applied solutions based on some search made, but the problem still there. Thank you so much for the help.

```
error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function ...
```

source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A
{
  public:

    struct data;
    typedef int (A::*func_t)(data *);
    typedef struct data
    {
      int i;
      func_t func;
    }
    data;

    data d;

    void process()
    {
        d.func(&d);
    }

    A()
    {
        d.i = 999;
        d.func = &A::print;
    }

    int print(data *d)
    {
        printf("%d\n", d->i);
        return 0;
    }

};

int main()
{
    A *a = new A;

    a->process();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And which line is the error on?

Comment: error in line 20, which is "d.func(&d);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `process` function attempts to call `d.func` but it is a pointer to member function. A pointer to member function must be called on some object. Presumably you want the instance of `A` to be `this`, in which case your `process` function should look like:

```
void process()
{
    (this->*(d.func))(&d);
}
```

Note the use of the `->*` operator to call a member function when you have a pointer to it.

Comment: @Nawaz Yeah, I tested just after I posted. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I tested, it also works. TO be clear, I mean "(this->*(d.func))(&d);" which is in the origin post.

Answer (score 3):

```
d.func(&d);
```

is not enough. `func` is a member-function-pointer which is pointing to a non-static member of `A`. So it can be invoked on an object of `A`. So you need to write this:

```
(this->*(d.func))(&d);
```

That would work as long as you write this inside `A`.

If you want to execute `func` from outside, say in `main()`, then the syntax is this:

```
A a; 
(a.*(a.d.func))(&a.d);
```

That is an ugly syntax.

Comment: I agree this is the correct syntax.  I would advise more to using `function` and `bind`, like @Joachim Pileborg suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have already said you need to say `(this->*d.func)(&d)` to call a pointer-to-member function (because you need to provide the object that it's a member *of*)

Another option is to make the function a static function, which doesn't need special syntax to call. To do that, change the typedef like so:

```
typedef int (*func_t)(data *);
```

Then make the `print` function static:

```
static int print(data *d)
{
    ...
}
```

Now you can just call `d.func(&d)`

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately what you are trying to do will not be possible, the reason being that `print` is not a `static` member function. This means it expects an implicit first argument that is the `this` pointer.

I suggest you try using the [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) function, something like this:

```
class A
{
    struct data
    {
        std::function<void(const data&)> func;
        int i;
    };

    data d;

public:
    A()
    {
        d.func = std::bind(&A::print, *this);
        d.i = 999;
    }

    void process()
    {
        d.func(d);
    }

    void print(const data& my_data)
    {
        std::cout << my_data.i << '\n';
    }
};
```

---

Of course, since the `print` function now have a proper `this` pointer, you no longer need to pass the data structure to it:

```
class A
{
    struct data
    {
        std::function<void()> func;
        int i;
    };

    data d;

public:
    A()
    {
        d.func = std::bind(&A::print, *this);
        d.i = 999;
    }

    void process()
    {
        d.func();
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << d.i << '\n';
    }
};
```

Comment: I largely agree with the `std::function` usage, but 'what OP is trying to do' looks possible to me (apply a member function to an object).

Comment: Entirely possible, just use the right syntax, or change the `func_t` type and make `print` static. `std::function` is OTT.

Answer (score -2):

Calling pointer the members require the class it is a member of to be the this param.

Try:

```
A a;
a.*(d.func)(&d);
```

Comment: Check other answers, you'll see why.

Comment: @Griwes Are you talking about not using 'this'? Do you think that downvoting would helped more that telling me than by commenting?

Comment: I am talking about syntax problem in your answer. Watch closely what others said.